# Opera not obeying caption-side CSS property when table set to inline block?

Tags: css, opera, css-tables

I'd just like some clarification on whether this is correct behavior or a bug with Opera.

The `caption-side` property is meant to determine the placement of a caption around a table, and there's 3 possible values that it can hold. Top, bottom, and inherit.

If I have a table set to a display value of inline-block, yet try and set `caption-side:bottom;`, it refuses to and keeps the caption at the top, which is the default behavior. Is this expected? No other browser has this issue.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QvaPu/8/) demonstrating this effect (note, I'm using Opera 11.60). What I'd like to know is if this is expected behavior, how I can fix it (can't change `display:inline-block;` on the table because I'm vertically positioning it within another element), and whether it has been fixed in newer versions of Opera...

Comment: Confirmed this behavior at Opera 12.16 (the last version that use Presto). But if you're _only_ using `display:inline-block` to achieve vertical-align, would it be easier if you wrap a inline-block `div` around the table instead?

Comment: Isn't table supposed to use `inline-table` for a style? (Not that that was ever implemented in any browser, but I'm just saying.)

Comment: @MrLister Good call! `inline-table` works: http://jsfiddle.net/QvaPu/9/ . And according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility), `inline-table` is well supported down to IE8.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks for the property... I can also can confirm it works! Still a weird bug though.